# Specifying the records to be deleted from a database using the TableAdapter.Update method

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-3.5, system.data.datatable

I have been messing with this for quite some time now and it's getting less and less fun; I followed the [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233823(VS.80).aspx) for deleting a row from a datagrid. And it works for *any* row however I am not able to specify the row... essentially I can delete random rows by using the `CurrentIndex` parameter anything I try to be more specific gets me a conversion errors.

In a nut shell 'FindByID' (my Primary Key) gives me 'object to long' errors etc. Can't nail down the row I want removed.

```
    //int ThisRow = radGridView1.CurrentIndex.Value;

    // Locate row for deletion
    VSConnectorDataSet.TestTableRow oldTestTableRow;
    oldTestTableRow = vSConnectorDataSet.TestTable.FindByID(
                      Int64.Parse(radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value));
    // Delete the row from the dataset
    oldTestTableRow.Delete();

    // Delete from database
    this.testTableTableAdapter1.Update(this.vSConnectorDataSet.TestTable);

    //DataRow rowDel=vSConnectorDataSet.TestTable.Rows[ThisRow];
    //rowDel.Delete();
    //testTableTableAdapter1.Update(vSConnectorDataSet);
```

Comment: What's `radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value`?

Comment: @p.campbell The FindByID is what VS2008 conjours up for me and is my primary key (an INT) in the database, value of which I can not parse to long (a requirement for FindByID).

Comment: @SLaks Telerik radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value would change dependant onthe selected row.

Comment: What is its actual value? (In the debugger)

Comment: @SLaks as an example '11' is the value

Comment: Did you check that in the debugger?

Comment: I did indeed, and I checked it against the Database ID they tally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Int64.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3.aspx) takes a string only. Perhaps try:

```
long selRowVal = (long)radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value;
oldTestTableRow = vSConnectorDataSet.TestTable.FindByID(selRowVal);
```

or

```
Int64.Parse(radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
```

It's not clear what datatype the `Cell.Value` is. Perhaps an explicit cast might help.

Comment: @confussedinwales: great, glad to have helped! On StackOverflow, you upvote and 'mark as answer' those people who've helped you find your solution. In this case, it looks like casting/converting to a `long` was correct. I'd be happy to take an upvote and green checkmark if you're willing!

Comment: @p.cambell I did try to VoteUp after reading your response however it says it requires 15 rep!?! So now I realised you can have more than one answer..... :)

Answer (score 0):

having found how to Convert.ToInt64 I am now able to target my deleted row via the bound dataset-tableadapter-database method.

```
private void DeleteToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    long ThisRow = Convert.ToInt64((radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value));
    DialogResult DelEntry = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete the entry titled '" + radGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["SparesTitle"].Value + "'?", "Delete this entry?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    switch (DelEntry)
    {
        case DialogResult.OK:
            // Locate row for deletion
            VSConnectorDataSet.TestTableRow oldTestTableRow;
            oldTestTableRow = vSConnectorDataSet.TestTable.FindByID(ThisRow);
            // Delete the row from the dataset
            oldTestTableRow.Delete();
            // Delete from database
            this.testTableTableAdapter1.Update(this.vSConnectorDataSet.TestTable);
            break;
            //
            // To Do - Give Slected to another row; having just deleted our 'CurrentRow'
            //
        case DialogResult.Cancel:
            break;
    }
}
```